# Clearing text area in Python ToDo-app GUI

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, text

I've already did a cool little CLI To-Do app in python, and now I'm trying to build a basic GUI around it. The main buttons, field in place, and yesterday I've figured out how to redirect the return string from my Todo class to the text area.
My problem now is how to clear the text area? Currently if I press the 'View button' it's continously redirecting the text without deleting the previous output. I've tried to create a function with

self.text.delete('1.0','end') + the function with the string output, but it's not working. Can you suggest me something? Thanks in advance!

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox as mbox
from todo_app import ToDo, arguments
import sys


class ToDoGui:
    def __init__(self, root):
       self.t = ToDo()
       self.root = root
       self.mainframe = tk.Frame(self.root, bg="white")
       self.mainframe.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

       self.build_grid()
       self.build_banner()
       self.build_text_area()
       self.build_buttons()
       sys.stderr = TextRedirector(self.text, "stderr")
       self.entry()


def build_grid(self):
        self.mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight=0)
        self.mainframe.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight=0)


def build_banner(self):
    banner = tk.Label(
        self.mainframe,
        bg="orange",
        text="PyKeep",
        fg="green",
        font=('Helvetica', 24)
    )
    banner.grid(
        row=0, column=0,
        sticky='ew',
        padx=10, pady=10
    )

def build_buttons(self):
    buttons_frame = tk.Frame(self.mainframe)
    buttons_frame.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky='nsew',
                                         padx=10, pady=10)
    buttons_frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    buttons_frame.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
    buttons_frame.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
    buttons_frame.columnconfigure(3, weight=1)
    buttons_frame.columnconfigure(4, weight=1)

    self.clear_button = tk.Button(
        buttons_frame,
        text='Clear',
        command=self.text.delete('0.0', tk.END)
    )

    self.view_button= tk.Button(
        buttons_frame,
        text='View list',
        command=self.t.list_view
    )

    self.add_button = tk.Button(
        buttons_frame,
        text='Add task',
        command=None
    )

    self.remove_button = tk.Button(
        buttons_frame,
        text='Remove task',
        command=None
    )

    self.complete_button = tk.Button(
        buttons_frame,
        text='Complete task',
        command=None
    )
    self.clear_button.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='ew')
    self.view_button.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ew')
    self.add_button.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky='ew')
    self.remove_button.grid(row=0, column=3, sticky='ew')
    self.complete_button.grid(row=0, column=4, sticky='ew')

def entry(self):
    entry_field = tk.Entry(self.mainframe, bd=2)
    entry_field.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='nwse', padx=10, pady=10)
    entry_field.insert(0, 'Enter task OR number of a task')
    entry_field.focus()

def build_text_area(self):
    text_frame = tk.Text(self.mainframe, wrap="word")
    text_frame.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='nsew',
                                    padx=10, pady=10)

    text_frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    text_frame.config(state=tk.DISABLED)
    text_frame.tag_configure("stderr", foreground="#b22222")
    self.text = text_frame
    return self.text

class TextRedirector(object):
    def __init__(self, widget, tag="stderr"):
        self.widget = widget
        self.tag = tag

    def write(self, str):
        self.widget.configure(state="normal")
        self.widget.insert("end", str, (self.tag,))
        self.widget.configure(state="disabled")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    ToDoGui(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Yes, I've tried that. 
    self.clear_button = tk.Button(
       buttons_frame,
       text='Clear',
       command=lambda: self.text.delete(1.0, 'end')
      )
not clearing the field.

Comment: What does "not working" mean? To delete a text widget you do exactly what you said you tried: `self.text.delete("1.0", "end")`.

Comment: You don't need all this code to reproduce the problem. Please remove everything that's not strictly related to the problem. All you should need for the problem is one text widget and one button,and the code to clear the window that you say isn't working. See http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contents you are trying to delete is not `Text`'s contents. It's your `Entry` widget.

```
def entry(self):
    entry_field = tk.Entry(self.mainframe, bd=2)
    entry_field.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='nwse', padx=10, pady=10)
    entry_field.insert(0, 'Enter task OR number of a task')
    entry_field.focus()
    self.entry_field= entry_field #make entry widget class' object

#since there is only one row in common Entry, you need to only specify starting index 
self.clear_button = tk.Button(..., command=lambda: self.entry_field.delete(0, tk.END)
```

Comment: Thanks! It solved my problem but I can't figure out why.
Can you lighten me up please?

[pic of the program](https://github.com/greenfox-velox/szepnapot/blob/master/week-05/pykeep.png)
So my entry widget is the top where you can enter a task or number to add/remove etc.
And I need to delete the entry_field not the text, why?

Comment: @p3ter_l0dri [`Text`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm) and [`Entry`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm) widgets are different items. You are putting your writings into Entry widget with `entry_field.insert(0, 'Enter task OR number of a task')` so you should remove it from there.